# NSTimer does not start or continue on Apple Watch following quick wrist lower and raise

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, apple-watch, watchos-2

My apple watch app has an NSTimer running, to repeatedly call a function. When running on device, and the wrist is lowered, the timer stops calling, and when it is raised, the timer resumes calling.

However, if the wrist is lowered and then raised quickly, the timer stops, but then does not resume calling the function. I have also tried invalidating the timer and starting a new one when the wrist is raised, however this results in the same problem, the timer does not repeatedly call.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and have any advice?

Comment: Just found someone else with the same problem here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16553

Comment: I have the exactly the same issue and I'm investigating about the runloop.